# Visual Studio Code command "dnx run" not available

Tags: dnx, visual-studio-code

I'm hoping some of you out there have tried out visual studio code for OSX and have gotten it to work with a simple C# console application.

I tried following this guys tutorial, linked below.

[Creating and Debugging C# Console Apps with Visual Studio Code on OSX](http://michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/)

My problem is that the command "dnx run" is not showing in my command line options in visual studio code. The command "dnx run" works from the terminal, but doesn't show in visual studio code as an available command. All I see from visual studio code for dnx is below.

[image: VSCode dnx options screenshot]

Additionally I noticed the tutorial tells you to run "dnx .run" from the terminal, this doesn't work for me, it says the command ".run" is invalid, but "dnx run" does work and successfully runs the console application. I'm wondering if that might have something to do with it.

Some background info:

1.) installed dmvm by running this:

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh

2.) installed dnx mono by running this:

dnvm upgrade -r mono

3.) installed yeoman by running this:

npm install -g yo

4.) installed aspnet generator by running this:

npm install generator-aspnet

5.)ran "yo aspet" and chose console application and named it.

6.) ran "dnu restore" in directory of console app.

7.) ran "dnu build" in directory of console app.

8.) go to run "dnx .run" and get an error saying command not found. Run command "dnx run" and successfully runs console app.

9.) "dnx run" command (or any form of it) is not available from VSCode and it appears it should be according to the tutorial.

I realize this isn't really a code question, but resources on the web are pretty low or confusing regarding getting VScode up and running. Also i'm not a big OSX expert. Does anyone know why I don't see this command from VSCode?

Maybe the tutorial is outdated and dnx run is not available from VSCode anymore or something like that?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. dnx works perfectly from the terminal but doesn't work through Code. Seems to me like it's some kind of environment variable problem.

Comment: See my answer below, hopefully it fixes your situation.

Comment: I have this problem to and the @mgmedick  solution didn't work for me.

Comment: When you navigate to the folder in terminal that contains your project.json file and run "dnx run" does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dnx run" command is not available from vscode because its not in the project.json commands section by default.

I had to change my project.json from this

```
    "commands":
     {
                "ConsoleApplication": "ConsoleApplication"
     },
```

to this

```
    "commands":
     {
                "run": "TestConsoleApp"  //this is the name of your application folder.
     },
```

Now type ">dnx run" into the VSCode command section and you should see it available.

Comment: I did this, but still got nothing when I typed "dnx run"

Comment: have you tried running "dnx run" (via the terminal) in the folder that contains the project.json file? What if you just type "dnx" in your terminal and hit enter, do you get anything?

Answer (score 2):

DNX is obsolete and no longer used or maintained.DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI. See:[.NET Command Line Interface](https://github.com/dotnet/cli)

Try running the command `dotnet run` in your project folder.

Comment: But, what about projects that use Mono? I don't want to use .net core for my project.

Comment: @Sonic use Visual Studio for mono project.

Comment: I wanted to use VSCode because it is multi-platform. You can't run Visual Studio on Debian or even Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the C# Extension installed. This is not mentioned in the tutorials.

Solution:
Extensions -> Install -> C# (by Microsoft)