# VS Code Command Palette DNX missing

Tags: visual-studio-code, dnx

I am attempting to use DNX in VS Code.  Instructions online suggest that if I have a DNX project folder open in VS Code then I should be able to open the Command Palette and type `dnx` and see some options.  However, when I open VS Code and type `dnx` I see no options.

[image]

Where do the commands in the command palette come from?  What causes them to populate?

This is different from [Visual Studio Code command "dnx run" not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939368/visual-studio-code-command-dnx-run-not-available) because that user sees `dnx` in their command palette, they just don't see the sub-commands.

Note: I am followed the instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/) to get my project setup and everything works fine except for the missing `dnx` in Command Palette.

Note: `dnx` is available on my path and I can do `dnx run` from the root of my project.

Comment: You can't refer to some third party site to show us what you did as those can disappear tomorrow and all hope is lost for those with the same issue.

Comment: I don't believe the exact steps I followed are relevant, just possibly helpful to someone trying to reproduce my problem in an attempt to answer.  That being said, I should probably re-arrange the question so that the steps I was following that lead me to the problem aren't as prominent.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the `dnx` command gets added to the Command Palette when you install the `C#` extension in VS Code.  To do this open the Command Palette and type `ext install c#`:

[image]

Comment: I have same exact issue following same example. But the C# install did not solve it for me. Is OmniSharp a running service on your side ?

Comment: I am now using `dotnet cli` as I have upgraded to RC2, so I don't have DNX anymore I don't think.  Are you still on RC1 and using DNX?